# How to change position of a button in titanium

Tags: android, iphone, titanium-mobile

i tried hard to figure this out but no success. Simple thing i want to do is to change the position of a button. I found `rect` property but it takes `Dimension`object as value.Sorry, but i'm not able to create object for `Dimension`. i try this way

```
var dim = new Dimension();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really an `Dimension` object. For iOS you would call this a dictionary.

To change the position of an element in Titanium you shoul use

```
Ti.UI.createButton({
  left: <left>,
  right: <right>,
  top: <top>,
  bottom: <bottom>,
  width: <width>,
  height: <height>,
});
```

Of course you don't need to set all the values but only all them you need.

The `size` and `rect` property is also only for read purpose not for write or changing.

[This](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View) and [this](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Layouts,_Positioning,_and_the_View_Hierarchy) provides useful instructions